# ld: library not found for -lPods-... with custom build configuration

Tags: cocoapods

I added a testing-configuration to add preprocessor macros when running unit tests, now I can't run my unit tests any more with that configuration in place, I always get

````
```ld: library not found for -lPods-MyProject```
````

my testing scheme:

[image]

what am I missing here?